# Merge and group by several arrays

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I need to merge associative arrays and group by the name. Say I have such 3 arrays:

```
ARRAY1
    "/path/file.jpg"  =>  2, 
    "/path/file2.bmp" =>  1,
    "/file3.gif"      => 5,

ARRAY2
    "/path/file.jpg"  =>  1, 
    "/path/file2.bmp" =>  1,
    "/file3.gif"      => 0,

ARRAY3
    "/path/file.jpg"  =>  1, 
    "/path/file2.bmp" =>  1,
```

I need to merge these arrays to one and group them by filepath and have result of sum of their values. Something like:

```
SELECT filename, SUM(val) FROM files
GROUP BY filename
```

But with multiple input arrays. Arrays are short (around 20 elements max). Each array might have different size.

Comment: Is your input arrays or SQL data? Confused.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I brought the SQL statement as an analogy to what I need in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*one possible way*

```
$rtn = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key=>$val)
{
  $rtn[$key]+=$val;
}

foreach ($array2 as $key=>$val)
{
  $rtn[$key]+=$val;
}

foreach ($array2 as $key=>$val)
{
  $rtn[$key]+=$val;
}
```

the above will assign the `filename, SUM(val)` as an associative array into `$rtn`

Comment: Works perfect. Fits my situation very well :) just added array_key_exists($key,$resultgarray) condition to get rid of notices. Thanks!

Comment: you can use `if (!isset($rtn[$key])) { $rtn[$key] = 0; }`

Answer (score 2):

**[EDIT: I adapted the function (as suggested by John Green) to use [func_get_args](http://en.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) so you don't need to put all the seperate arrays in one array before you can use it.]**

I think you could use the following function.

```
mergeArrays()
{
    $return = array();
    $arrays = func_get_args();
    foreach ($arrays as $array) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
            if (array_key_exists($key, $array) {
                $return[$key] += $val;
            } else {
                $return[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: array_key_exists() has different arguments syntax. first key, then array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `RecursiveArrayIterator`

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($paths));
foreach ($iterator as $path => $value) {
    $summed[$path] = isset($summed[$path]) ? $summed[$path] + $value : $value;
}
print_r($summed);
```

or `array_walk_recursive` and a Closure

```
$summed = array();
array_walk_recursive($paths, function($value, $path) use (&$summed) {
    $summed[$path] = isset($summed[$path]) ? $summed[$path] + $value : $value;
});
```

Both will give

```
Array
(
    [/path/file.jpg] => 4
    [/path/file2.bmp] => 3
    [/file3.gif] => 5
)
```